# MS Access Mark Duplicates in order of appearance

Tags: ms-access, duplicates

I am fairly new to MS Access and I need to figure out the best way to mark duplicate instances of a value a new column in ascending order. I have written a script in python that accomplishes this in ArcGIS but I need to figure it out for access. I have a `FIELDS` Column with the names I want to check for duplicates and a `DUP_COUNT` column I want to have populated with the number of times a value has occurred.  So the first instance would be designated 1 the second 2 and so forth. I tried doing something similar in MS Excel and I figured out how to mark the first occurrence of a value but not proceeding ones.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)>1,IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1,"1","2"),"")
```

Example:

```
FIELDS DUP_COUNT
Smith          1
Smith          2
Smith          3
Smith          4
Brown          1
Brown          2
```

Comment: What is first? There is no first in a relational database other than the order you impose. Do you have a date / id or do you want a random first?

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear about this, the order doesn't matter at all to the point that I could just as easily have 4 populated next to each field if there are 4 duplicates of that name. In my python script I had just had each field added to a list and then returned a number for each instance and so I figured I would try and do it the same way in access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us say you have a unique ID, you might say:

```
SELECT dups.FIELDS, dups.ID, (
    SELECT Count(*) 
    FROM dups a 
    WHERE a.Fields=dups.Fields And a.ID <= dups.ID) AS RankOfDup
FROM dups
ORDER BY dups.FIELDS, dups.ID;
```

To simply get a count of duplicates, you can say:

```
SELECT ID, Count(ID) FROM dups 
GROUP BY dups.ID 
HAVING Count(dups.ID)>0
```

Comment: Thanks Remou this works great! If I wanted to check if the unique ID was unique could I use a similar method. I don't mean to ask a second question as much as clarify the use of this method.

Comment: To check for duplicates, you would normally just count. `

Comment: Thanks a lot sorry for my inane questions

Comment: Not inane, just questions. Ask away.